# What are these types of "crunches" called and details about them? And are they harmful?

Tags: exercise-technique, calisthenics, crunches

This may seem a little bit funny, because I don't even know if they exist!

I saw this in the anime *Dragon Ball Z*. Goku, hanging upside down with his hands on his neck, touches his head to his knees without letting go of his hands from his neck.  Like so:

[image: Goku training in space]
([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8yMWHchI7U))

If these exist, how to do them? And what is the number I should try to achieve?  I currently do 6-7 in one go.

Some other examples:

[image: Example 1]
([source](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2617350/It-looks-slightly-batty-celebs-swear-new-fitness-craze-Could-hanging-upside-banish-mum-tum.html))
[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you doing this exercise? On the bar or bench. I suggest you doing it on the bench like the second picture  because when you hang from the bar you swing back and forth and thats not good for core strengthening. You see that woman is stable because she found multiple bars, so she is not swinging.  Doing it like her is okay highly recommended. Upper abs are the main muscle group working in this exercise so you need to put a program to keep tracking your progress.

**Its not harmful when you do it with a limit**

*So, how to do them? *
You just try to lift yourself up to your toes as far as you can. If you feel weak that means you are not good enough for this level. Also do not stay at this position for long time because you will get **dizzy**

3 Sets:

- 5 reps
- Rest 15 Seconds
- 5 reps

This seems easy and it is so when you get more advanced try these:
3 sets:

- 15 v-ups
- 20 side leg raises each leg
- 100 Flutter kicks

So the answer is: yes this exercise exists but I personally don't do it. Leg raises are more functional for getting ripped :-D

Comment: I do it on a single bar. And I think it has contributed significantly. And when you say "15 sec rest" then do you mean to say that keep hanging or to get off the bar and stand on ground? And what is the name of exercise? And what are v-ups?  Flutter kicks? I am new, so please..

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal 15 sec rest on the ground not hanging. Idk whats the name. V ups is advanced. watch it on youtube and Flutter kicks are again difficult. YouTube bro! Everything is in there just search

Comment: **"100"** flutter kicks!??

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal yes its burning and it rips your abs. If you feel not strong enough do sets of 50 or 25. As I said its advanced program

Comment: Thanks for your help, but cannot choose it as the best answer. :( Question still unanswered. Name?

Comment: Name doesnt really marter. Hanging crunches

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal if you are covered with these information mark the question as answered

Comment: Ive searched for naming. Some people say "inverted crunches " some other say "upside down crunches"

Comment: Ohk thanks. How to count flutter kicks? Like we count a pair of kicks as 1 or one kick as 1?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal you count a pair of kicks as one repetition

Comment: I did 66 in one go, the first time. Then 82. Now lets see.

Comment: I am 15 btw? Is it alright?